# Magento: Can't get attribute value for last item in cart

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

I'm running into a problem with getting attribute values for products that have been placed in a users cart.

I have the following code:

```
umask(0);
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();

foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());

$attributeValue = $_product->getAttributeText('availability');

echo $attributeValue;

}
```

And it works fine for all products in the cart except the very last one. For example, I'm trying to get the value of an "availability" attribute I've created that can have only 1 of the following values "Backorder", "Preorder", "Out of Stock". If I have 3 items in my cart I can get the correct values for the first 2, however for the last item it just displays "No".

I have double checked each item to make sure all attributes are set correctly and it happens with any number of items in the cart.

Hopefully it's just a stupid mistake on my part.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

SOLVED:

Changing:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
```

to

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
```

Fixes the issue.

Comment: If you will print out `$_product->getId()` instead of your attribute will you get the correct IDs?

Comment: Ah, that was it. Changing that bit to $item->getProductId() gives the correct product ID and it is now printing the correct attributes.

Comment: Ok. I will add it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, i'll vote up your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in that line:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
```

With `$item->getId()` you are getting ID of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` and not  `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`. You have to use `$item->getProductId()` instead to get ID of actual product associated with current quote item.